# How to include a external library in JavaScriptCore?

Tags: ios, objective-c, javascriptcore

I am trying to load a external library via JavaScriptCore

Specifically I want the end result of this:

```
<script src="fancyLibrary.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But with the syntax of this:

```
JSContext *context = [[JSContext alloc] initWithVirtualMachine:[[JSVirtualMachine alloc] init]];
[context loadExternalJavascriptFileWithName:@"fancyLibrary.js"];

JSValue *fancyFunction = context[@"fancy"];
```

Is this possible at the current time? I figure I can include the external library in the app bundle and call it from there. It's a matter of loading the library into the context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to use the evaluation API to load the contents of the script in the context. This is actually pretty close to what a browser does when it encounters a script tag.

```
NSURL *scriptURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"path/to/fancyLibrary.js"];
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *script = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:scriptURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
[context evaluateScript:script];
```

Comment: what if you need to add a new block referencing the external file you just brought over?

Comment: What do you mean? Could you elaborate, please?

Comment: sure. Similar to webpages when loading jquery external file first before being able to write your own custom jquery code.
would you do two evaluateScript, one for the brought external file and one for the js block!?

Comment: Exactly, just evaluate a new script in the same context.