# Swift: How to use JavascriptCore to call a function in a loaded file

Tags: javascript, swift

Similar to a regular js file that starts with referenced external query and then your js custom code, I need to do the same in Swift using JavascriptCore.

I saw this Objective-C [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23408577/1019042):

```
NSURL *scriptURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"path/to/fancyLibrary.js"];
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *script = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:scriptURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
[context evaluateScript:script];
```

It does the first part of bringing down an external js file, but I want to also add a js block calling some of the functions in that referenced file. How do I do that!? Can you do it in Swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just call `evaluateJavascript` on the webView to call functions and get information, so you can do things like:

```
webView.evaluateJavascript("someFuncton();") { (result, error) in
    if (!error) {
         print(result(
    }
}

webView.evaluateJavascript("document.height") { (result, error) in
    if (!error) {
         print(result(
    }
}
```

You can even post messages from the Javascript back to native swift functions using webKit using message hanlders. see this [ref](http://nshipster.com/wkwebkit/)

Here is an objective-c [guide](http://www.joshuakehn.com/2014/10/29/using-javascript-with-wkwebview-in-ios-8.html) on sending messages both ways using Javascript

Comment: It is a function of WKWebView but it requires a completion handler which I forgot about, see the documentation for it [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKWebView_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/WKWebView/evaluateJavaScript:completionHandler:). My code was in swift

Answer (score 0):

For a complete answer, you want to:
1. inherit from WKNavigationDelegate
2. in viewDidLoad:

```
self.webView.navigationDelegate = self
```

3. and calling it in the didFinishNavigation, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27852788/1019042)