# Including jQuery library in JavaScriptCore

Tags: jquery, swift, xcode, javascriptcore

I am trying to use jQuery functions in JavaScriptCore, so I have executed the jQuery library as a script in my JSContext. However, after I do that, I still can't access any jQuery functions. Here's a stripped-down version of my code in a Xcode playground:

```
import JavaScriptCore
let context = JSContext()

//Evaluate JQuery library in context:
do {
let libString = try String(contentsOf: URL(string: "http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js")!, encoding: .utf8)
context?.evaluateScript(libString)
} catch (let error) {
    print("Error while processing URL: \(error)")
}

//Access variables defined by JQuery library:
 print("'$' in context is defined as: \(context?.objectForKeyedSubscript("$"))")
 print("'jQuery' in context is defined as: \(context?.objectForKeyedSubscript("jQuery"))")
```

This prints:

> '$' in context is defined as: Optional(undefined)
>
> 'jQuery' in context is defined as: Optional(undefined)

If I had included the library correctly, those would be defined as functions. What have I done wrong? Should I even be using JavaScriptCore to gain jQuery functionality?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include a external library in JavaScriptCore?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23397658/how-to-include-a-external-library-in-javascriptcore)

Answer (score -1):

You should include jQuery library:

```
NSString *commond = @"window.onload=function(){var jq=document.createElement(\"script\");jq.setAttribute(\"src\",\"https://ss0.bdstatic.com/5aV1bjqh_Q23odCf/static/superman/js/lib/jquery-1.10.2.js\");document.getElementsByTagName(\"head\")[0].appendChild(jq);window.setTimeout(\"exec()\",1000)};function exec(){document.write($(\"body\").get(0))};";

[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:commond];
```

Comment: Format your answer properly using the editing hints.  This should be highlighted as code.  Then explain why this code answers the question and how it solves the problem.

Comment: The question was about JavaScriptCore, not WebView.